# Displaying Dictionary Data in a message box

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter, paramiko

I am trying to create a simple app using tkinter wherein a user would execute
several commands on remote machine using paramiko and then the results of those commands will be saved in a dictionary with command as key and stdout data as value.

I am confused as in how to show that data in human readable form using message.showinfo box in tkinter also if i could get any help with letting the user save that data with a button.

here is the code that I am struggling with.

```
try:
        ssh.connect(_ipaddress,username=_username,password=_password)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(_StingrayVersion)
        _report.update({"STINGRAY_VERSION":stdout.readlines()})
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(_CheckStingrayStatus)
        _report.update({"STINGRAY_STATUS":stdout.readlines()})
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(_CheckJbossStatus)
        _report.update({"JBOSS_STATUS":stdout.readlines()})
        msg.showinfo(title="Report", message=str(_report))
except Exception as e:
        msg.showinfo(title="Login", message=e)
```

Comment: Using `msg.showinfo(title="Report", message=pprint.pformat(_report))` might make the output more readable. The [`pprint.pformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html?highlight=pformat#pprint.pformat) function supports several optional keyword arguments to customize the string it produces. Otherwise you can write your own function that formats the data in the dictionary the way you would like.

Comment: "save that data with a button" is way too vague. Save it in what sense and in what format?

Comment: That helps a lot. I need to look further on this. Thank you so much.

Comment: The data that appears on the message box, I want to save that data in a doc file with a custom name. I went through asksaveasfile function from filedialog, that would do.

Comment: You can easily save it in a file as plain text using `asksaveasfile` and even use `pprint.pformat()` to format it. However, writing to .doc file will be more involved and you'll probably want to third-party module to do it (there's more than one version of it). Here's one module I heard about called [`docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).